# Agree (or disagree) inequality $a\leq b$ then $a^n\leq b^n$ for all $n\geq 0, n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a,b\in[0,1]$?

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b\in[0,1]$.  Agree (or disagree) if $a\leq b$ then $a^n\leq
>  b^n$ for all $n\geq 0, n\in\mathbb{R}$?

I try to find example. Let $a=0.2$ and $b=0.5$. I try to plot the function as below. Red graph is $0.5^n$ and blue graph $0.2^n$. So, I can conclude if $a\leq b$ then $a^n\leq b^n$ for all $n\geq 0$, $n\in \mathbb{R}$.

Generally, does that inequality holds? I'm confused to conclude it, (maybe there are counterexamples)?

[image]

Comment: Yes. The function $x \mapsto x^n$ is increasing over $[0,1]$ for every integer $n$.

Comment: $n$ is real numbers.

Comment: Worst notation ever, but this does not change anything !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\leqslant b$, then either $b=0$, in which case $a=0$ and so $a^n\leqslant b^n$ indeed, or $b>0$, in which case $\frac ab\leqslant1$. And, for any $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\frac ab\leqslant1\implies\left(\frac ab\right)^n\iff\frac{a^n}{b^n}<1\iff a^n\leqslant b^n.$$

Note that I did not use *at all* the fact that $a,b\leqslant1$.

Comment: You used the fact that $a,b \geq 0$, though :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it holds.
$$a\le b \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}\le1 \Rightarrow \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n \le1 \Rightarrow a^n \le b^n$$ for all $$n \in \mathbb{N}.$$